# Player in Spaceship

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, space, rigid-bodies

I want to realize space game on Unity3d engine. There are some huge spaceships in the void. So, I want players flying in space in weightlessness, but when they go inside any spaceship, they will be under the influence of local gravity field of spaceship (if it is in `On` state).
I going to do it using `addForce()` function applied to `rigidbodies` of players towards spaceship floor. But with this approach Players will be only magnify to a floor, but not to stay on they feet automatically.
**How can I put they on they feet the best way?**
 Or, maybe, anybody knows the completely different approach to solve this custom gravity fields issue?
PS: It will be a multiplayer game with many ships with different orientation in space with a lot of players in them. Each ship has it's own gravity field.

Comment: This seems to be a quite specific question about game development using Unity. Maybe you should ask [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: use this and keep track when they are in or out of the ship and change it accordingly http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-gravity.html

Comment: @JRowan, there are several spaceships in the space with different orientation, so can I set several global gravity fields?

Comment: you should make a "gravity" script with different vector3 for each ship and change accordingly whenever you enter each ship

Comment: @JRowan, different players will be in different spaceships.

Comment: here check this out, i dont think you can set multiple gravitys, your best bet is probably making up for it with addForce() http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24240/changing-gravity-for-one-object.html

Comment: @JRowan, and what should I do with player orientation inside the spaceship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result I consider to applying the gravity by myself. Just note that Gravity is an acceleration, not a force. Meaning when applying I use "ForceMode.Acceleration". That acceleration could simply be the exact opposite of up direction of current spaceship. I'm talking about "-transform.up" of spaceship. I can also use same Up vector, to rotate player so that gravity actually feels right, aka. player feet are pointing towards gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it will be online multiplayer
you could maybe change the gravity for the client (local player)
and disable `useGravity` for the other players on the network
thus you would be affected by gravity in whatever direction
but everyone else is affected by the gravity set on their "Side".
(assuming that the movement of them is being handled by the clients and not the server or host).
This might cause troubles with floating objects..
 if you have those a simple addforce as you are using it now might be enough for creates or any object.